# $C_G(E)= E \times{\rm PGL}_k(q)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, classical-groups, centralisers

Let $r$ be an odd prime and $q$ a power of a prime $p$ where $r\neq p$.

If $r^m|n$ and $q\equiv1$ (mod $r$), then $r^{1+2m}.{\rm Sp}_{2m}(r)\le{\rm GL}_n(q)$ and $Center(r^{1+2m}.{\rm Sp}_{2m}(r))\le Center({\rm GL}_n(q))$ .

So $r^{2m}.{\rm Sp}_{2m}(r)\le{\rm PGL}_n(q).$

Let $G={\rm PGL}_n(q)$ and $E=r^{2m}$.

How do I see $C_G(E)= E \times{\rm PGL}_k(q)$ where $n=r^{m}k$.

Intuitively ${\rm PGL}_k(q)$ makes sense since $r^{1+2m}\leqslant {\rm GL}_{r^{m}}(q)$ can be embedded as $r^{1+2m}\otimes I_k$ in ${\rm GL}_n(q)$. But I fail to come up with a rigorous proof.

Comment: It is useful to know that if $R=r^{1+2m}$, then $C_{Aut(R)}(R/Z(R))=Inn(R)$.

Comment: thank you for your input. Would you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Let $X=GL_n(q)$ and $\bar X=G=PGL_n(q)$ and write $\bar x$ for the image in $\bar X$ of an element or subset $x$ of $X$. Let $P\le X$ with $P\cong r^{1+2m}$, $Z(P)\le Z(X)$, and $\bar P=E$. Let $g\in C_G(E)$ and choose $x\in X$ such that $\bar x=g$. Then the useful fact implies that $x$ induces an inner automorphism on $P$. So $x=yz$ where $y\in P$ and $z\in C_X(P)$, $g=\bar y\bar z\in E\overline{C_X(P)}$. Now you need to compute $C_X(P)$.

Comment: many thanks for the elaboration!